# How do I make page numbers skip note slides

Tags: beamer

I am putting together a beamer presentation. I have notes for each page so that when I send the slides to my co-authors they have an idea of what I am going to say on each slide, what I am going to emphasize, etc. so they can give me feedback. Some prefer the notes, some do not, so I send them out according to the preference. However, when I compile with notes on and `\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number]` in the preamble, the notes are numbered along with the slides, so that when I get notes back saying "fix the typo in slide 6", or when I want to discuss the slides with more than one person, the slide numbers are different.

How can I set the template such that the page/slide numbers only show up on the slides and skip the notes?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Pittsburgh}
\setbeameroption{show notes}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]

\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{Title}
\framesubtitle{Subtitle}
This is some text
\note{This is a note}
}
\end{document}
```

The result I would like is for the notes to not be numbered, but to keep the style.

If I use samcarter's solution below, the note template (defined in `beamerouterthemedefault.sty`) gets redefined and all of the formatting gets wiped out. Alternatively, I can go into `beamerouterthemdefault.sty` and copy/paste the entire definition into my preamble, adding in the page counter line. I can also edit the default style file to include this line, which will get overwritten the next time beamer is updated.

It may be that what I want is not possible with `beamer`, in which case I'll stick with copying the entire definition into my preamble and adding the one line, or else writing a new theme that incorporates these changes when I am not against a deadline.

Last edit:
The above actually gets me very close to what I want. Taking out the re-definition of the notes page keeps the style, takes the page numbers off the notes, and only increments each frame. The only minor quibble is that now if I have multiple parts within a frame (using `only` or `uncover`, for instance) they all show up as the same frame number. I can work with this, but would still like to know if there is a way to do this with page numbers.

Comment: Have you tried putting the notes outside the `\frame`s, i.e.: `\frame{Frame1} Note1 \frame{Frame2}`?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\setbeameroption{show notes} 

\setbeamertemplate{note page}{%
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \begin{minipage}{2.1\textwidth}
        \normalfont 
        \fontsize{20}{34}
        \selectfont 
        \insertnote
    \end{minipage}

}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        test
        \note{testnote}
    \end{frame}

    \begin{frame}
        test2
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, I had used `[slide number]` instead of `[frame number]`. Is there a way to just add the page counter to the existing note template instead of re-writing it in the preamble? I am using the `Pittsburg` template, and the notes page has the section/subsection structure in the header, a picture of the slide in the corner, and other structural elements. I will not be able to have two screens for the notes and presentation, so I'd like to be able to print the notes for my practice talk and have the visual clues to know which notes go with which slide.

Comment: @craigim: It might be the easiest, if you add a MWE to your question

Comment: I added both a MWE and some clarification to my question.

Comment: Actually, after all that, taking out the definition and _only_ using `[frame number]` gives me close to what I'm looking for. Slides with multiple parts are all numbered the same so that I show 12 slides instead of 18, for instance, but I can work with that.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to add a single command to a template, use `\addtobeamertemplate`:

```
    \addtobeamertemplate{note page}{%
        \addtocounter{page}{-1}%
    }{}
```

However, I must admit that command didn’t solve the numbering issue for me, numbers are still completely insane when I’m using the presenter’s notes

Comment: In my case though, the page numbers aren’t exactly sequential, and I haven’t found a proper cure for this, except as switching the presenter’s notes off, see the [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/sh4qQTC.png).